# PHP not working after updating from 5 to 7

Tags: apache2, php

I updated PHP 5 to PHP 7, but I noticed the old version was still configured in my Apache server, so I uninstalled it. Then everything got messy and being all this confusing as this is unless you're an experienced administrator, I just reinstalled apache2 with PHP 7.

However, now the PHP module is not even working because text is being rendered plainly. I am trying to reinstall the PHP 7 module into my apache server but something weird is happening:

When I try installing it with `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0`, I am getting a dpkg error, but the module is being installed because if I run `sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php7.0` it can be uninstalled.

So what can I do? How can I properly install and configure the PHP 7 module in Apache?

**Edit**

I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and got this output:

```
Configuring libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.7-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ... 

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):   
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 

Errors were found processing:
    libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Comment: Could you include the data from the dpkg error, please?

Comment: I can't. That's the thing. There is no description of the error, just " Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)".

Comment: Ah!  I see.  What's the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Configuring libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.7-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were found processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0

(I had to translate so it might not look exactly the same than the original English message)

Comment: done, check it out

Comment: Try `dpkg -r libapache2-mod-php7.0` then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.  Does it give a clean output now?

Comment: Yes I get a clean output now. But when trying to install lib-apache2-php7.0 again, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Okay.  Sorry for giving you so much homework, but do you mind including the last few lines from `/var/log/dpkg.log`?

Comment: No worries, it's me who's annoying you ;)

http://pastebin.com/jXXNzN5Z

Comment: Say, with `libapache2-mod-php7.0` unistalled, if you do an apache2 restart, does it work?  From my reading, it appears that that module may be optional, used only for certain applications.

Comment: I mean, apache2 works yes. But it doesn't have php...

Comment: If you run `dpkg --get-selections | grep php5`, are there any packages that still have the `deinstall` status?

Comment: Running that returns a clean output.

Answer (score 0):

Disable 5.6 mod first

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
```

Now you should enable PHP7 ones:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

To reflect changes Apache restart is required:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```